# MVC5 article System with ApplicationUser As Property to get user info

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2, custom-properties

Hi im working on a Article page and have a model for articles that takes a ApplicatonUser Property..

```
    public class postModels
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public postModels parentPost { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        [Required]
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string post { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser appUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastEdited{ get; set; }
    }
```

in my Razor View i Try this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created)
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastEdited)
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.appUser.NickName)


        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><h1>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.post)</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output for everything except the ApplicationUer property works.. 
Thanks for the help and interest :)

Comment: What is not working? Does `appUser.NickName` contain a value?

Comment: Not working = Exception? or rather nothing is shown?

Comment: Stephen -> i tryied to debug. it seems to get the proper user ,
TommySM -> No error is thrown its just empty

Comment: @KimYangJacobsen, Debug your code. What is the value of `NickName`. If its not showing its because it does not have a value.

Comment: Stephen Muecke Looks like the item.appUser is null..

Comment: @KimYangJacobsen, `item.appUser` is not `null` (if it was your code would throw a `NullReferenceException`) - `NickName` is `null`!